# Printing time values along with pose

Tags: ros, navigation, nav-msgs, move-base, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m an absolute newbie and I got hold of someone’s simple program to navigate a robot by setting a goal position and including random obstacles. The python script uses ROS move_base and navigation packages, subscribes to nav_msgs and prints out pose and twist outputs to the terminal/a text file. Everything works fine but I’m not able to figure out the time values for each pose/twist output. How can I get the script to output time; or is it an output frequency parameter set in any of the yaml files. I tried searching and I could not figure out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321792/printing-time-values-along-with-pose/) by [kkulkarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40101/kkulkarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess your script subscribes to `nav_msgs/Odometry` messages since you said you have a twist output. If you check the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) of the message you'll find that there are different fields :

```
std_msgs/Header header
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance twist
```

Your script gets the info from the fields `pose` and `twist`, if you want to get the time you have to check in the field `header` , and within the `header` there is the field `time`.

So in your script you probably have a print function with something like `data.pose.pose.position` in it. You just have to add `data.header.time` somewhere in your print.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kkulkarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40101/kkulkarn/) on 2019-04-24**:
Yes, you are correct on the pose and twist. I tried including what I thought would be the correct syntax., which obviously not. Gave me an error saying bad call back. What am I doing wrong?

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('anvel_2dnav')
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Header

def navCallback(data):
    print "---------------------------"
    print data.header.time
    print data.pose.pose
    print data.twist.twist
if __name__ == '__main__':

rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, navCallback)
rospy.Subscriber("time", Header, navCallback)
```

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-04-25**:
Your error is because of the last line, just get rid of it. With a subscriber, you are supposed to give a topic name, the type of the topic and the name of the callback. The first subscriber already subscribe to the topic `odom` and you will deal with the `Odometry` message within the `navCallback` function. Since the `data` do have the `header` field there is no need to have another subscriber.

To go further on your issue : your last line try to subscribe to the topic `time` (which I feel it doesn't exist, if you do `rostopic list` there shouldn't be this topic) specifying that the topic is a `Header` msg (this type do exist but is usually used within another message, just like inside `Odometry.msg`) and you assign a callback that is already assigned to another message type.

I would recommand you to go through the [ros tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) to understand the different ROS concepts :)

**Comment by [kkulkarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40101/kkulkarn/) on 2019-04-25**:
Got it. Noted on reviewing the tutorials. I was in a hurry and excited to see some initial results without really understanding all the communications between ROS and the dynamics solver. Thanks.